# Check for tkinter events globally (across OS)

Tags: python, tkinter

I trying to make an application with a pop-up menu - when I type SPACE-R_ALT on my keyboard, globally across the OS (Windows in my case). When that happens, I want to pop-up a window (I know how to do that), and it is crucial that I can happen to be using Chrome or Word, then tap Space-Right Alt, then be able to open up this little menu.

Tkinter event bindings have two problems:

1. First, when I use an event binding for <Key> and then, in the
   function, use evt.keysym, I can see that the program can't register
   both at the same time. I could use a timer and then see if it works,
   but I would prefer one line that fixes it all.
2. Second, I find that tkinter event bindings only work when the binded widget's window (or window itself) is FOCUSED. I will hide my root and TopLevel at all times, and so is not focused.

I would appreciate any help on this. If your suggestion uses another module, I don't really care, as long as it works on Windows 10 (not Mac OS X, not Linux, but Windows). I'm also using Python 3, but any version (aka 2) would also be okay, as I could either try to port YOUR suggestion to Py3, or port MY code to Py2. Thanks!

Comment: OS doesn't send events to hidden windows (it doesn't matter whether it is Python, C, C++, etc). Maybe you need [pyhook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/) module . Or you can use [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) but it use own script language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with Furas's help - with Pyhook I can wait for events globally, and then tie in the event with tkinter events.