# Tkinter bind copy event needs to work in background as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a simple copy paste event, which should trigger a function while my program runs:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.bind('<Control-c>', parse_item) 
root.mainloop()
```

`parse_item` grabs the contents of the clipboard and makes some calculations.

**The problem I have is:**

It only works if my program is in focus. I need to be with the mouse in the program, then the bind event will trigger.

**What I need:**

The bind event should also trigger if the program is not in focus (for example the program is minimized). It should always trigger while the program runs.

Comment: Python has no control over the handling of keystrokes when the program in not in focus.

Comment: I can use pynput.keyboard.Listener. That will work as a script, but I'd like to have a GUI for the user, which he can use to close/stop the script. Any ideas which tools I can use here?

Comment: It doesn't matter what Python module you use — it doesn't change the fact that OS is in control when your script doesn't have focus. There may be ways of writing a background daemon or system service written in Python. How to do something like that will depend on what OS you're using.

Comment: @Roman ***"I can use pynput.keyboard.Listener."***: If you are abel to do it with `pynput`, then use it as a background service to notify your `tkinter` GUI using some sort of [Inter-process_communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: Does this answer your Question: [tkinter-hide-and-show-window-via-hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570446/python-tkinter-hide-and-show-window-via-hotkeys). Relevant [check-for-tkinter-events-globally-across-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980603/check-for-tkinter-events-globally-across-os)

Comment: @All thanks for the replies. I have already a working solution. It works in background. I use the tkinters `after()` method to call an other method every second. The other method simply checks whether clipboard content changed and if yes it does something. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> It only works if my program is in focus. I need to be with the mouse in the program, then the bind event will trigger.

You cannot do that with tkinter. It can only operate on events in widgets that it controls, and only when it has focus.  You would have to use a platform-specific tool to intercept events from other programs.